# web3 Websocket connection to infura

Tags: web3js, infura, websocket

I receive this error when I'm trying to connect to the websocket

*WebSocket connection to 'wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received*

Code snippet

```
import web3 from 'web3';
var web3lib = new web3(
  new web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws'),
);  
console.log(
  'provider in web3 eth: ' + JSON.stringify(web3lib.currentProvider),
);  
console.log('New block in web3 eth: ' + web3lib.blockNumber);
var subscription = web3lib.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function(
  error,
  result,
) { 
   if (!error)
       console.log("output of web3 stream"+JSON.stringify(result));
       else
  console.log('Error of web3 stream ' + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

was fixed on `web3@1.0.0-beta.36` https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1559#issuecomment-412348642

Answer (score 4):

This is working

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws'));

const subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', (error, blockHeader) => {
if (error) return console.error(error);

console.log('Successfully subscribed!', blockHeader);
}).on('data', (blockHeader) => {
console.log('data: ', blockHeader);
});

// unsubscribes the subscription
subscription.unsubscribe((error, success) => {
if (error) return console.error(error);

console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
});
```

Took this example provided by https://github.com/egalano

https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/29#issuecomment-365128914

Comment: I am again getting the same error for this piece of code also. I am using web3.js 1.0.0-beta.34. Would that be a problem or else what to check?

Comment: Did you try with any other version?

Comment: 0.20.6 version worked on HTTP and it doesn't have Websocket. Which version are you using?

Comment: `web3@1.0.0-beta.34`

Comment: I updated to web3@1.0.0-beta.35 and started getting the same error. Wouldn't happen with beta-34 or beta-33

Comment: this works with `...beta.36`

Answer (score 3):

It seems a value of WebSocket request header is invalid.

More specifically say, a value of `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` is `undefined`.

According to the github issue below, the issue was introduced from `web3@1.0.0-beta.34`

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1559

I confirmed `web3@1.0.0-beta.35` has not fixed the issue yet in my environment. So downgrading to `web3@1.0.0-beta.33` is needed if you use WebSocket at this moment.

Comment: Yeah downgrading worked for me. Thanks for the find.

Comment: Still now also?

Answer (score 0):

using your infrua ID to replace MYID :

```
client, err := ethclient.Dial("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/MYID") 

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

headers := make(chan *types.Header)
sub, err := client.SubscribeNewHead(context.Background(), headers)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for {
    select {
    case err := <-sub.Err():
        log.Fatal(err)
    case header := <-headers:
        fmt.Println(header.Hash().Hex()) // 0xbc10defa8dda384c96a17640d84de5578804945d347072e091b4e5f390ddea7f

        block, err := client.BlockByHash(context.Background(), header.Hash())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        log.Printf("TX:%s", block.Hash().Hex())          // 0xbc10defa8dda384c96a17640d84de5578804945d347072e091b4e5f390ddea7f
        log.Printf("Height:%d", block.Number().Uint64()) // 3477413
        log.Printf("Time:%d", block.Time())              // 1529525947
        log.Println(block.Nonce())                       // 130524141876765836
        log.Printf("#:%d", len(block.Transactions()))    // 7
    }
}
```